# Where can I find a catalog of known Ramsey numbers?

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory, graph-colorings

Is there an online catalog available of Ramsey numbers, preferably one that for unknown values documents the known upper/lower bounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MathWorld has a pretty decent list (scroll down in the link) and cites numerous papers with good bounds

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html

Answer (score 12):

See "Small Ramsey Numbers" at http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1

Comment: The URL didn't work for me until I added "www."

Comment: I've updated the link.